# Why builtin times doesn't work in pipeline?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, pipe, shell-builtin

I've the following sample script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sleep 5
printf "times cmd: "
times
printf "pipeline: "
times | ( read user sys; echo $user; )
printf "head: "
times | head -n1
printf "times cmd again: "
times
```

with the following output:

```
$ ./test.sh 
times cmd: 0m0.003s 0m0.005s
0m0.001s 0m0.001s
pipeline: 0m0.000s
head: 0m0.000s 0m0.000s
times cmd again: 0m0.003s 0m0.006s
0m0.003s 0m0.004s
```

Question is, why `times` command resets time when used with a pipeline? Is there any way to avoid it in order to parse the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a pipeline, all commands are run in a subshell. `times` reports time spent by the shell and its subshells, but not its parent shell.

You can try process substitution instead:

```
times > >( head -n1 )
times > >( read user sys ; echo $user )
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of which shell we are talking about.
On this shell, I get:

```
$ times
0m9.805s 0m3.372s
39m29.072s 0m15.537s
```

Because it has been running for a while.
However, a sub-shell will report zero:

```
$ ( times )
0m0.000s 0m0.000s
0m0.000s 0m0.000s
```

And, as a pipeline is executed in a sub-shell for each part of it:

```
$  sleep 10 | times
0m0.000s 0m0.000s
0m0.000s 0m0.000s
```

If you run the command above, you should see the `times` output immediately (as it does not depend on the pipe) and the shell prompt return 10 seconds latter.

#### Workaround?

Stay in "this" shell:

```
$ times > >(read user sys; echo "$user")
```

Then, why do you need times? Could `time` or the more powerful `/usr/bin/time` work for you?

Use time:

```
$ TIMEFORMAT="%R;%U;%S"; time { sleep 1; }
1.001;0.000;0.000
$ TIMEFORMAT="%U"; time { sleep 1; }         #### If you only want user.
0.000
```

Enclose several process in braces:

```
$ time { wc /etc/hosts; sleep 2; }
 21 115 327 /etc/hosts

real    0m2.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Use the more powerful external `time` (sadly it only works in external executable files):

```
$ /usr/bin/time wc /etc/hosts
 21 115 327 /etc/hosts
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed ?%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 534maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+109minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: `times` reports cumulative user, system and child times as far as consumed by the _current_ shell while `/usr/bin/time` reports that info only for the processes runned on its command line, at the end of their execution. So, while the suggested workaround is good (and it's what I was looking for, thanks), the suggestion about use `time` instead of `times` may not.